# Redux Toolkit Query (RTK Query) ignoredPaths- any examples?

Tags: serialization, redux-toolkit

Is there any documentation on the format for the paths in ignoredPaths? is it the url for the specific endpoint and method?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the example from the [official usage guide](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide):

```js
configureStore({
  //...
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        // Ignore these action types
        ignoredActions: ['your/action/type'],
        // Ignore these field paths in all actions
        ignoredActionPaths: ['meta.arg', 'payload.timestamp'],
        // Ignore these paths in the state
        ignoredPaths: ['items.dates'],
      },
    }),
})
```

There are some docs on the options here but not the format specifically:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware#options